# Modify subelement based on another subelement in an XML using python

Tags: python, xml

I have the following XML file:

```
<root>
 <input_file>
   <type>x</type>
   <path>hi</path>
 </input_file>
 <input_file>
   <type>y</type>
   <path>hi_again</path>
 </input_file>
</root>
```

and am trying to modify the `<path>` values based on the `<type>` values such that:

```
<root>
 <input_file>
   <type>x</type>
   <path>bye</path>
 </input_file>
 <input_file>
   <type>y</type>
   <path>bye_again</path>
 </input_file>
</root>
```

I have the following code:

```
items = {'x':'bye', 'y': 'bye_again'}
tags = ['input_file','type']
for v in items.keys():
    destination = root.xpath(f'//{tags[0]}/{tags[1]}[text()="{v}"]/..')[0]
    new_elem=LET.fromstring(f'<path>{items[v]}</path>')
    destination.replace('path', new_elem)
LET.indent(root, space="  ")
print(LET.tostring(root).decode())
```

with no success.  Is there something I am not understanding?  Should I modify the value instead of replacing it?

Thanks.

Comment: XSLT is the best technology for the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using xpath and lxml, try:

```
for target in root.xpath(f'//{tags[0]}'):
    old = target.xpath(f'./{tags[1]}/text()')[0]
    target.xpath('./path')[0].text=items[old]
print(etree.tostring(root).decode())
```

Output should be your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT based solution.

The remaining part is just to launch XSLT transformation in Python.

**Input XML**

```
<root>
    <input_file>
        <type>x</type>
        <path>hi</path>
    </input_file>
    <input_file>
        <type>y</type>
        <path>hi_again</path>
    </input_file>
</root>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="path">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="preceding-sibling::type='x'">bye</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="preceding-sibling::type='y'">bye_again</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>unknown</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output XML**

```
<root>
  <input_file>
    <type>x</type>
    <path>bye</path>
  </input_file>
  <input_file>
    <type>y</type>
    <path>bye_again</path>
  </input_file>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

see below - just a simple loop (no external library is required)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


items = {'x':'bye', 'y': 'bye_again'}

xml = '''<root>
 <input_file>
   <type>x</type>
   <path>hi</path>
 </input_file>
 <input_file>
   <type>y</type>
   <path>hi_again</path>
 </input_file>
</root>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
for f in root.findall('.//input_file'):
    f.find('path').text = items.get(f.find('type').text,'unknown')
ET.dump(root)
```

output

```
<root>
 <input_file>
   <type>x</type>
   <path>bye</path>
 </input_file>
 <input_file>
   <type>y</type>
   <path>bye_again</path>
 </input_file>
</root>
```